# Outlook cant send intent pdf file in 7 android

Tags: android, email, outlook

Sorry for my english. In everething email client it code work fine. I send some files to email client and then if need edit this message and send from email client. But in outlook i have error:

```
Failed to attach attachments
```

Bellow my code:

```
String theme = "Test";
 ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < pdfs.length; i++) {
            File fileIn = new File(pdfs[i].getAbsolutePath());
            fileIn.setReadable(true);
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
            uris.add(u);
        }

      Intent emailIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
     emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

    String to[] = {sendTo};
        emailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        emailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SUBJECT, theme);
        emailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, context.getResources().getString(R.string.text_email_message_body));

        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an Email client:"), 1);
```

I tryed `setType` text/plain, application/octet-stream, message/rfc822 nothing work

**UPD:**

I go to  Settings -> Applications -> Application Manager -> Outlook -> Permissions and enable the "Storage" permission manually and everething is work. But how i can enable permission  automaticaly when i send file outlook?

Comment: Please have a look here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @Kyrmyzyanik, OP does not need that for his own app but for an external app. Please read again.

Answer (score 0):

You better do not mess around with permissions of other apps.

Instead you should use a file provider to serve your files